# Loop Variable Accessibility Issue

Tags: apex, batch, loop

I have a unit test with this context data:

```
    List<Contact> testCon = new List<Contact>();
    testCon.add(new Contact(AccountId = '0014000000zoemWAAQ', LastName ='Accounts Payable', Email = 'Email2@e.com', status__c = null));
    testCon.add(new Contact(AccountId = '0014000000zoJj1AAE', LastName ='George', Email = 'Email4@e.com', status__c = 'Billing Primary'));
    testCon.add(new Contact(AccountId = '0014000000zoz3NAAQ', LastName ='Erikson', Email = 'Email3@e.com', status__c = 'Billing Contact'));
    testCon.add(new Contact(AccountId = '0014000000zoz3NAAQ', LastName ='Le', Email = 'Email1@e.com', status__c = null));
    testCon.add(new Contact(AccountId = '0014000000zoemWAAQ', LastName ='Nguyen', Email = 'Email5@e.com', status__c = 'No Longer There;Billing Primary'));
    testCon.add(new Contact(AccountId = '0014000000zoemWAAQ', LastName ='Bannon', Email = 'Email7@e.com', status__c = 'Role1;Role2'));
    insert testCon;
```

I have some code like this:

```
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context){
       return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, AccountId, Email, LastName, status__c FROM Contact]);

}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Contact> scope) {
         for(Contact con : scope) {

            //NPE avoidance condition for production environment
            if(String.isNotBlank(con.email) && String.isNotBlank(con.AccountId) ) {

                  if(String.isNotBlank(con.status__c)) {
                    //do something
                  }
       }
}
```

No matter what I do `String.isNotBlank(con.status__c)` returns false. Despite the unit test clearly loading the context data with that field entered, other than the first line which is intentional.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you executing your batch instance? Are you using `Test.startTest()` & `Test.stopTest()` in your unit test?

Comment: Additionally, please provide info about the object model - specifically what is the type of the Status__c field? (I'd also ask why your batch doesn't apply the Email, AccountId and Status__c field filtering in the query locator - what you have shown in the question is highly inefficient since you have apex running against contacts that are not relevant and is limiting you to a maximum of 50 million contacts on your org...

Comment: please don't use hardcoded accountIds in your unit test - they will fail once you deploy to Production or any Staging org - instead, have your testmethod insert mock Accounts